# in c++ gtk::drawarea: how to refresh image

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I am using gtkmm for a GUI in C++.
I have a `Gtk::DrawingArea` on which I have an image (filename):

```
class MyArea : public Gtk::DrawingArea
{
public:
    MyArea(string filename)
    {
        m_image = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file(filename.c_str());
    }

    virtual bool on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr)
    {
        if (!m_image)
            return false;

        Gtk::Allocation allocation = get_allocation();
        const int width  = allocation.get_width();
        const int height = allocation.get_height();

        // Draw the image in the middle of the drawing area, or (if the image is
        // larger than the drawing area) draw the middle part of the image.
        Gdk::Cairo::set_source_pixbuf(cr, m_image, (width - m_image->get_width())/2, (height - m_image->get_height())/2);
        cr->paint();

        return true;
    }
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> m_image;
}
```

I would like to have a function that change the image (with filename2). But I can't find how to :-/

Could someone help me with this please. Thank You

Comment: I have tried to call `draw()`, or `signal_draw` after creating another m_image with my filename2 but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a member of your class:

```
void change_image(string filename2)
{
    m_image = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file(filename2.c_str());
    queue_draw();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I already wanted to try this, but "on_draw" has a parameter that I don't have :-/

Comment: TY. It works. But I don't understand why "on_draw" is not called at the constructor :-/

Comment: @Jav Because the constructor is constructing the *concept* of a `MyArea`.  It can exist without being visible or even without having a screen.

Comment: can I force the drawing? I would like to save the cairo::context ; save it at the first call, and then restore it when I want to remove the drawing that I made... Is that possible? Thank You in advance

Comment: @Jav queue_draw forces the drawing. Saving the context will go horribly.  The context could change. There could be several contexts.

Comment: Thank You very much !! everything works perfectly now. Thank you for your help, your comments were very usefull !